# Exception when acquiring access token from Azure Active Directory for Guest user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to acquire Azure Active Directory access token for a guest user in an Azure Active Tenant. I'm able to acquire access token for a regular user created in Azure AD, but when I user userName (email) and password for a guest user I'm getting an exception:

```
Accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Accessing WS metadata exchange failed
```

Inner exception:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).
```

Code responsible for acquiring the token:

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext($"{cloud}/{tenant}");
var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(user, password);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, client, credentials);
```

Link to MSND: [AuhtenticationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet)

I suppose the problem may not be related to the code but to the Azure Active Directory configuration.

I changed Azure Active Directory > Users > users Settings > External collaboration settings > Guest user permission are limited to NO but is did not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what the username are you usign ? Normally User Principal Name for guests is different for their emails , smth like gsamoogle_gmail.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: I was using user@gmail.com as username, when I'm using user_gmail.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com I'm getting 400 BadRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the login flow you are using doesn't really work well with federated users (like these Guests).
If you want to support them,
you will have to switch to using a different flow.
Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant flow that you are using here is only really meant to be a legacy upgrade path and isn't really modern authentication.

By the way, that login flow also does not support users with Multi-Factor Authentication or an expired password.

Depending on your app type, you can choose from different flows:

- Authorization code (back-end web app/native app)
- Device code (native app on device that can't show a web view)

In the case of a back-end Web app,
authorization code flow works by you redirecting the user to login,
getting a code back which you exchange for tokens.

In native apps it can be used by showing a pop-up of the login page to the user.
It can be used through different overloads of `AcquireTokenAsync()`.
Don't use the one accepting a `UserPasswordCredential`.

Device code requires you to use two functions on ADAL: `AcquireDeviceCodeAsync` and `AcquireTokenByDeviceCodeAsync`.
You call the first one, show the user the message given back,
and then await the second one.
The user will be required to open a browser,
and enter the code shown in the message there.
More info on this flow: https://joonasw.net/view/device-code-flow